# как выйти из такого бесконечного цикла

Tags: java

как выйти из такого бесконечного цикла

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main1 {
    static String s;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input password:");
        for (;;){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                s=br.readLine();
            }catch (Exception e){}
            System.out.println("error");
            if (s=="stop")
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("exit");
    }
}
```

Comment: то совершенно другой вопрос

Comment: Вопрос другой, но ответ на него показывает, почему у вас не останавливается цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени `if (s=="stop")`, на проверку `if("stop".equals(s))`. Ты сравниваешь не строки, а ссылки.